# WSO2 API Manager: Global disable keepalive

Tags: wso2, keep-alive, wso2-esb

Calling an endpoint service from WSO2 API Manager is using keep-alive, the requests show:

> TID: [0] [AM] [2014-01-30 12:43:17,747] DEBUG {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.headers} -  http-outgoing-2 >> Connection: Keep-Alive {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.headers}

It is a mandatory requirement to disable keep-alive requests.

*Note: we have set the debug soap messages*

```
log4j.logger.org.apache.synapse.transport.http.headers=DEBUG
log4j.logger.org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire=DEBUG
```

I wanna disable the keep-alive, based on http://charithaka.blogspot.nl/2013/01/how-to-disable-http-keep-alive.html by setting:

```
http.connection.disable.keepalive=1
```

After restart, I still see the keep-alive setting in the header

> TID: [0] [AM] [2014-01-30 13:03:18,682] DEBUG
>   {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.headers} -  http-outgoing-1 >>
>   Connection: Keep-Alive {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.headers}

*I changed the property, locally, in this service*

```
<property name="NO_KEEPALIVE" value="true" scope="axis2"/>
```

*This disables the keep-alive for this service.*

Why is the global setting not working?

Answer (score 0):

Please edit `repository/conf/passthru-http.properties` and set `http.connection.disable.keepalive=true`

Now WSO2 API Manager uses the pass-through transport

Comment: I set this propertie, but the logs shows something different:

TID: [0] [AM] [2014-01-30 14:31:19,056] DEBUG {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.headers} -  http-outgoing-1 >> Connection: Keep-Alive {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.headers}

Comment: Did you edit the correct properties file? Could you please double check? You should not edit nhttp.properties.

Comment: double checked :-(. It is still there: TID: [0] [AM] [2014-01-31 08:31:52,396] DEBUG {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.headers} -  http-outgoing-2 >> Connection: Keep-Alive {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.headers}
TID: [0] [AM] [2014-01-31 08:31:52,397] DEBUG {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire} -  << "Connection: Keep-Alive[\r][\n]" {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire}